# App keeps crashing after changing targetsdkversion using apk easy tool

Tags: java, android, flutter, apk

Im trying to change the apk targetsdkversion to 30 so i can upload it to google play and im using apk easy tool to change it but after changing it the app keeps crashing after i open it and i dont know why it keeps crashing. any help is welcome

This is my android manifest file and i cant understand why it keeps crashing if i try to use sdk 29 it works but when i put 30 it crashes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:compileSdkVersion="30" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="11" package="com.dancingskye.rollingsky" platformBuildVersionCode="30" platformBuildVersionName="11">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<meta-data android:name="CMPLAY_SYNC_IPC" android:value="com.cmplay.kinfoc.sync"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>>
<meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="25.3.1"/>
<application android:allowBackup="false" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.GameApp" android:supportsRtl="true" android:testOnly="false">
    <meta-data android:name="SET_PROMOTION_LOG" android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="51ab80af-cbe7-4e4b-8493-de4a37a54b1f"/>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="2"/>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.AppActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true"/>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.notification.Level8NoticationBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Level8NoticationBroadcast_Action"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.notification.NotificationDeletedBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="NotificationDeletedBroadcast_Action"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="7.1881595E11"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity"/>
    <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" android:value="UdAAPq-zrVhcaaKovlmPEn8qXmrUnzGFbRP_FOz5uehTE0G7l0X-nfpJPepBc3QCVrClEAr7qWa2XsAHshGdM4"/>
    <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.verbose_logging" android:value="false"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vuugle.warren.ui.VuugleActivity" android:theme="@style/vuugle_theme"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vuugle.warren.ui.VuugleFlexViewActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.mopub.common.privacy.ConsentDialogActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.RewardedMraidActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.CMCampaignTrackingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.commons.RollingSkyService" android:process=":service"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.webview.ui.WebViewActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.webview.broadcast.GameBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.webview.broadcast.gamebroadcast"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.webview.broadcast.WebBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.webview.broadcast.WebBroadcast"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <provider android:authorities="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.ipc_provider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.ipc.IpcProvider" android:process=":service"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity"/>
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1082192450000087" android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"/>
    <provider android:authorities="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
    <service android:name="com.cmplay.kinfoc.report.service.KinfocReportSerivce" android:process=":service">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="start_service"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.kinfoc.report.service.NetWorkChangeReceiver" android:process=":service">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.InnerPushService" android:process=":service"/>
    <provider android:authorities="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.innerpush_provider" android:exported="false" android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.ipc.IpcProvider" android:process=":service"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.ui.OpenScreenActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:theme="@style/innerpush_theme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.ui.OpenScreenVideoActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:theme="@style/innerpush_theme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.ui.InsertScreenActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:theme="@style/innerpush_theme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.video.IncentiveVideoPlayActivity" android:process=":inner" android:theme="@style/innerpush_theme"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.video.VideoAdDetailActivity" android:process=":inner" android:theme="@style/innerpush_theme"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.dancingskye.rollingsky.ad.interstitial.admob.AdmobTestActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentSoftwareActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.applovin.sdk.AppLovinWebViewActivity"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.aiming.mdt.adt.video.VideoActivity" android:screenOrientation="user" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.aiming.mdt.adt.interstitial.InterstitialActivity" android:screenOrientation="user" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.aiming.mdt.adt.interactive.InteractiveActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:name="com.aiming.mdt.adt.AdtActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.tapjoy.TJAdUnitActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.tapjoy.TJContentActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.tapjoy.InstallReferrerReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.tapjoy.TapjoyReceiver"/>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.youappi.sdk.AdActivity"/>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.webview.broadcast.GameBroadcast">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.webview.broadcast.gamebroadcast"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.webview.broadcast.WebBroadcast" android:process=":web">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.webview.broadcast.WebBroadcast"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.notify.NotifyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.notify"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name="com.cmplay.gppay.UnityPayActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"/>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"/>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"/>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"/>
    <activity android:label="Test By Network" android:name="com.google.ads.mediation.testsuite.activities.NetworkListActivity"/>
    <activity android:label="Test Network Adapter" android:name="com.google.ads.mediation.testsuite.activities.NetworkDetailActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
    <activity android:label="Native Ad Preview" android:name="com.google.ads.mediation.testsuite.activities.NativeAdActivity"/>
    <activity android:label="AdMob Mediation Test Suite" android:name="com.google.ads.mediation.testsuite.activities.InitialActivity"/>
    <activity android:label="Test By Ad Unit" android:name="com.google.ads.mediation.testsuite.activities.AdUnitListActivity"/>
    <activity android:label="Please select a country" android:name="com.google.ads.mediation.testsuite.activities.CountryListActivity"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: Nope i researched more and the problem is from the apktool because it lies about the appt version or smth like that and thats why